# How to make Kiosk mode on Pepper's tablet in android os?

Tags: android, locking, kiosk, pepper

I am trying to make my application run on kiosk mode in pepper tablet. i tried the following code but no luck,

```java
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setPackage("com.softbankrobotics.kioskclient");
intent.setAction("kioskclient.intent.action.CONFIGURATION");
intent.putExtra("LAUNCH_ID", getPackageName());
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to configure Kiosk mode is by using Command Center platform(no code needed and possibility to switch from on app to another one remotely). 
If you don't have access to it, you can contact the Customer Care of your region : https://www.softbankrobotics.com/emea/en/support

Otherwise
Once you have installed Kiosk Client application. Run your application then exit then start Kiosk Client Application by clicking on its icon.